# Making code unreachable

Tags: c#

What is the best way to mark code unreachable, so the compiler won't give an error message? 
A short example:

```
int x;
if (y == 0) x = 1;
else if (y == 1) x = 2;

Console.WriteLine(x);
```

I know that y can be 0 or 1, but C# will give a message that x desn't get all path a value. The real code is not this, but I wanted to keep it shorter.

Is throwing an exception a good practice, or is there other method?

```
int x;
if (y == 0) x = 1;
else if (y == 1) x = 2;
else throw new Exception();

Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Comment: You can always use Visual Studio's break point feature. That's the easiest way to monitor your codes status per line.

Comment: Exceptions are for what they sound for: exceptions. If y is not supposed to be anything else than 0 or 1, yeah, throw a new ArgumentException.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @Grant Well yeah, it all depends on the context in the end.

Comment: `I know that y can be 0 or 1` - some day, this will be false - and that's what the compiler is telling you (in it's own way)

Comment: Why assume that `y` is an argument? What exception should be thrown if it came from another source?

Comment: I didn't mean argument actually, just a local variable

Comment: But the method should never throw that exception, because it is checked earlier that it has a correct value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would go with throwing an exception - it indicates that the world is not in a state you expect, and you'd be better off quitting before you do any damage:

```
if (y == 0)
{
    x = 1;
}
else if (y == 1)
{
    x = 2;
}
else
{
    throw new IllegalStateException("y should be 0 or 1");
}
```

Alternatively, for simple situations like this, use a switch/case:

```
switch (y)
{
    case 0:
        x = 1;
        break;
    case 1:
        x = 2;
        break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalStateException("y should be 0 or 1");
}
```

(As noted in comments, if `y` is a method parameter, then `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` would be more appropriate. Or if `y` is only not-one-or-zero *because* of a parameter value, then again, indicate that cause. The above is appropriate if basically it's a matter of the overall state of the world being broken.)

Comment: @Kilazur Unfortunately the "mere mortals" have all answered *very* incorrectly.  I for one am happy that Jon's answer showed up here to aleviate the OP's woes ;)

Comment: y is a local variable, it has nothing to do with any object, or the caller. The exception would never be thrown, because it only depends on the function itself. It is thrown when something doesn't go as intended.

Comment: @KocsisDávid: Okay, that sounds like `IllegalStateException` is appropriate then.

Comment: It really looks strange to throw an exception, just to make sure it returns, or something gets a value

Comment: @KocsisDávid: Well that's often a sign that a design change would be a good idea. I might well have handled your situation differently, for example - but that's a different matter.